# C# UWP - FileStream access Denied

Tags: uwp, filestream, imgur

I try to read an image but I have this following error :

> "Access Denied to "C:\User\53324\Pictures\oldboy2.jpg""

code :

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\53324\Pictures\oldboy2.jpg", FileMode.Open))
    {
        image = await endpoint.UploadImageStreamAsync(fs);
    }
    Debug.Write("Image uploaded. Image Url: " + image.Link);
});
```

Comment: I would imagine either the file is in use or your program does not have permission to access that file location.

Comment: How to give access for my program ? thank's

Comment: Depending on who controls the file systems, a network administrator may have to grant you rights to that directory location, or you can try running your program as Administrator, if you are going to deploy this program and you need it to run as Admin, you may want to look into adding a manifest.

Comment: You're going to have a difficult time loading files like that in UWP. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions for recommended ways of loading files - you'll need permission in your app manifest to access the location, and you're probably better off loading as a StorageFile;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Access Denied to "C:\User\53324\Pictures\oldboy2.jpg""

Windows Store apps run sandboxed and have very limited access to the file system. For the most part, they can directly access only their install folder and their application data folder. Access to other locations is available only through a broker process. You could access `@"C:\Users\53324\Pictures\oldboy2.jpg"` via [`FileOpenPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker).

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to the picked file

}
else
{

}
```

For more, you could refer [Open files and folders with a picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(yourFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true);
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
```

Should work.